# Is there an auditory form of "paints a picture"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for an expression similar to "paints a picture" (e.g. "The sentence painted a picture of the town") that uses a metaphor focused on sound instead of on images. In other words, I want an expression that means "to describe artfully" that uses sound (music?) instead of paint.

Comment: Paints a musical picture....

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm really looking for something that uses a different word than paint though

Comment: Try to find something that parallels 'paints' when describing a soundscape.

Comment: I have seen the phrase "sound portrait" used to describe this.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22paints%20a%20musical%20picture%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: Pictures are generally far more accurately representative than even programme music. But you could use the general 'the music told the story of ...' or 'the music evoked the sights and scenes of the old town'.